# Mongoid force readonly mode

Tags: rspec, mongoid, rspec-rails, rspec3

I have a specific use case where I need to send test emails to some of my customers (ie so they know in advance what all of our emails look like, and they can check with their internal IT systems that no blacklisting will occur).

In order to achieve this is a very efficient way, I am reusing my existing factories so I can easily generate test data that I send to my mailers, and before each emails is sent, I overwrite the to/cc fields to add the test emails, and add `[test]` in the subject as prefix

I would like to write a test that ensures that no data is ever written to the database (ie my factories are used in a good way, using only `build` statements, especially when dealing with nested association build)

**I need to write a spec that ensures that the DB does not receive any write query (or actually any query at all) ie. that my "test code" is safe and won't create data in my production database with the factories.**

I wasn't able to find a way to do this so far, so instead I have added some code that iterates on all my collections and I run this

```
tested_models.each do |model|
  expect(model.count).to eq(0), "#{model.name} was persisted"
end
```

but I need to update this `tested_models` manually, so this isn't working well. I'm looking for a better solution. My hints

- Maybe find a way to force the mongoid adapter to use READ-ONLY mode, or create a readonly user, so I'd see messages like `Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: not authorized on myapp_test to execute command { insert: "messages", $db:`
- Stub one of the core Mongoid methods responsible for handling DB queries, [cf this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647759/rspec-expect-no-mongoid-database-query-fired) and issue [opened in Rspec](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-rspec/issues/225)

Answer (score 0):

To verify that no updates are sent by the application, you can use command monitoring in the driver (https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring) and check logged commands.

To prohibit updates to collections, you can set up roles in MongoDB (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/).